# Calling custom delegate of swift class from objective c class throws error

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

I have a custom delegate in (NewsDetailsVC.swift), Where I have to pass selected table cell text to another class (MainNewsVC.m) which is an objective c class.

NewsDetailsVC.swift

```
@objc protocol SelectedDataDelegate {
    func valuePassed(dataString: String)
}
class NewsDetailsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    weak var newsPageDelegate: SelectedDataDelegate?
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainNewsPage", bundle: nil)
    mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNews") as! MainNewsViewController
    mainVC.passedValue = selectedCell?.textLabel?.text
    print("text label value: ", mainVC.passedValue)
    newsPageDelegate?.valuePassed(dataString: mainVC.passedValue)
    print("text from delegates: ", (dataString: mainVC.passedValue))

}
```

MainNewsVC.h

```
@protocol SelectedDataDelegate <NSObject>

@end
@interface MainNewsViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate, SelectedDataDelegate > {
   NSString *newsValue;
   BOOL isFromSelection;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id < SelectedDataDelegate > receiveNewsDelegate;
-(void)valueChanged:(NSString *)newsString delegate:(id< SelectedDataDelegate >)theDelegate;
```

MainNewsVC.m

```
@synthesize receiveNewsDelegate;

-(void)selectQuestion:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:newsTable];
newIndexPath = [newsTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchLocation];
newsDetailsVC = [NewsDetailsViewController instantiate];
newsDetailsVC.SelectedDataDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:selectQuestionVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) valuePassed:(NSString *)newsString receiveNewsDelegate:(id< SelectedDataDelegate >)theDelegate {
[newsTable reloadData];
newsValue = newsString;
NSLog(@"newsValue: %@", newsValue);
isFromSelection = YES;
self.receiveNewsDelegate = theDelegate;
[newsTable reloadData];
}
```

In the above method when I tried self that custom delegate I am receiving error as "Property 'SelectedDataDelegate' not found on object of type 'NewsDetailsViewController *'". Any issues on the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedDataDelegate` is the name of the protocol, the property is named `newsPageDelegate`.